# shibboleth idp with OpenLDAP integration / Uncaught runtime exception java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Tags: shibboleth

I got install shibboleth idp with OpenLDAP integration
, it authenticate successfully but
it return   exception  error

```
Uncaught runtime exception java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

the log file contains

```
Attribute Resolver 'ShibbolethAttributeResolver': Removing result of attribute definition 'uid', contains no values
```

Attribute Resolver 'ShibbolethAttributeResolver': Removing result of attribute definition 'mail', contains no values

and
the attribute-resolver.xml file contains

```
<AttributeDefinition xsi:type="Simple" id="uid">
       <InputDataConnector ref="myLDAP" attributeNames="uid" />
         <AttributeEncoder xsi:type="SAML1String" name="urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:uid" encodeType="false" />
         <AttributeEncoder xsi:type="SAML2String" name="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3" friendlyName="uid" encodeType="false" />
    </AttributeDefinition>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I found that it's a bug in shibboleth idp 4.0  ,
it should be fixed in the next version